# C# FindWindow can't find game (Settlers 4)

Tags: c#, winapi

i'm writing a small "autosave" program for settlers 4.

The program should send "CTRL + S" every X seconds to make a quick-save ingame.

When i try the code below with notepad, everything works fine. But when i try it with the game (Settlers 4) it always opens the message box and tells me, that it can't find the game (game is running of course).

The game runs in fullscreen and doesn't need administrator rights, if that is important.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Siedler4Autosave2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lp1, string lp2);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Find Settlers 4
        IntPtr handle = FindWindow("S4_Main", "Die Siedler IV");
        if (!handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (SetForegroundWindow(handle))
            {
                // send "CTRL + S"
                SendKeys.Send("^(s)");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Settlers 4 not found
            MessageBox.Show("Siedler 4 nicht gefunden");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: From the documentation, the first argument is a "class name", and you can pass NULL if you want to search all windows. Maybe give that a shot. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: that helped me alot! works perfect now, thank you!!